# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x03416540>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the error " at 0x03416540>" while running the following code.
How do I print the list ?

    `def add(x,y):
        return x+y
    def even(x):
        return x%2==0
    a=[1,2,3,4]
    b=[17,11,11,10]
    result = filter(even, map(add,a,b))
    print(x for x in result)`

Comment: `x for x in result` is a generator. That's what's printed. Use `print(*result)`, instead.

Comment: That isn't an error, that is printing a generator-object, which is what you told it to do.